# How can I run a GET request to each element in an array then store the result in another array and pass it as props?

Tags: reactjs, express

I have an array of related product IDs. I am looping over that array to run a GET request so that I can retrieve the product info for each related product ID. I am then storing each result to a relatedProductsInfo array, eventually setting that as relatedProducts (using useState) to pass it as props of a child component. However, the relatedProductsInfo array turns out to have 0 element. Due to this issue, I cannot map through the relatedProductsInfo array (I'm trying to make a card for each related product info).

relatedProductsInfo gives the following:

final related products info: > []

When clicked on the arrow, it gives an array of 2 data objects (each product ID's info in an object). Length says 2, but I also see [[Prototype]]: Array(0).

```
// MAIN APP
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import OutfitList from './OutfitList.jsx';
import RelatedProductsList from './RelatedProductsList.jsx';

const RelatedItems = ({productId, setproductId, productInfo, setproductInfo}) => {
  const [relatedProducts, setrelatedProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    GetRelatedProductsList();
  }, [])

  let GetRelatedProductsList = () => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/products/${productId}/related`)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log('related product IDs: ', res.data); // [37315, 37319]
      let relatedProductIds = res.data;
      let relatedProductsInfo = [];

      relatedProductIds.forEach((id) => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/products/${id}`)
        .then((res) => {
          relatedProductsInfo.push(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log('failed to retrieve related product info: ', err);
        })
      })

      console.log('final related products info: ', relatedProductsInfo); // see above
      setrelatedProducts(relatedProductsInfo);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('failed to retrieve related product IDs: ', err);
    })

  }

  return (
    <div>
      <RelatedProductsList relatedProducts={relatedProducts} setproductId={setproductId}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default RelatedItems;
```

Comment: forEach is not going to give you the expected results . It's most likely returning from your function before awaiting the results. You can use something like Promise.all() which takes an array of promises. Here's an example : https://jsfiddle.net/RyanZee/pawvxjuk/3/

Comment: @RyanZeelie I'm still very confused... do you mind showing it to me by code?

Comment: Not sure if it's working since I can't call your API . But it's a step in the right direction. https://jsfiddle.net/RyanZee/chzxopsu/7/

Answer (score 3):

As you are using API to get data which is an asynchronous task javascript will execute the next lines. To store the product details in `relatedProductsInfo` you can use `Promise.All` or an async and await for the API calls.

Using async and await

```js
let GetRelatedProductsList = async() => {

  const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/products/${productId}/related`);
  console.log('related product IDs: ', res.data); // [37315, 37319]
  let relatedProductIds = res.data;
  let relatedProductsInfo = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < relatedProductIds.length; i++) {
    const id = relatedProductIds[i];
    const result = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/products/${id}`);
    relatedProductsInfo.push(result.data);
  }

  setrelatedProducts(relatedProductsInfo);
}
```

Or
If you don't want to use for loop you can use `Promise.all()`

```js
let GetRelatedProductsList = async() => {

  const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/products/${productId}/related`);
  console.log('related product IDs: ', res.data); // [37315, 37319]
  let relatedProductIds = res.data;
  let relatedProductsInfo = [];

  const results = await Promise.all(relatedProductIds.map((id) => {
    return axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/products/${id}`)
  }));

  results.forEach((result) => {
    relatedProductsInfo.push(result.data);
  });


  setrelatedProducts(relatedProductsInfo);

}
```

Comment: Nice. Out of interest. Would mapping the ID's in the Promise.all() still trigger the calls at the same time? Or would it be better to map them and then promise.all the result of the map. Like in the first example, it's going to await the repsonse before firing off the next request. You could also just .then(x=>x.data) in the promise.all instead of doing another forEach

Comment: Yes Instead of ```results.forEach``` you can do  .then(res => {}).